# Prove that no function $f : Z → {1, ..., 100} $ is one-to-one.

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

This seems obvious to me, but I'm not sure how I would prove it.
Is simply proving $|Z| > |{1...100}| $ sufficient? If so, how would I go about proving that? I know Cantor's theorem that says some infinite sets are bigger than others, and I can show show by showing a surjective function exists between them, but does this same rule apply for comparing an infinite set to a finite set?

Comment: Prove that between $f(1),f(2),...,f(101)$ there are at least two values that are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the statement $|\mathbb{Z}|>|\{1,\dots,100\}|$ is precisely the same as ``there is no one-to-one function from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\{1,\dots,100\}$.'' In order to actually show that there's no one-to-one function, consider the pigeonhole principle: if there are $n$ balls distributed among $b$ buckets, then some bucket contains at least $n/b$ balls. Here, your balls are the elements of $\mathbb{Z}$ and your buckets are the elements of $\{1,\dots,100\}$.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier than that. Note that if $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\{1,2,...,100\}$ is one-to-one then $f(1),f(2),...,f(101)$ are $101$ different elements in $\{1,2,...,100\}$ which is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose some such $f$ *is* 1-1. Then the 100 sets $f^{-1}(n)$ each contain at most one point, are pairwise disjoint, and exhaust $\mathbb Z$. This is impossible.